# Why my UL lists are displayed horizontal?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, footer

I am trying to make my footer displays 4 `<ul>` horizontal but it displays it vertically
I tried `display:inline;`  but it didn't work
here is the code

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.row::after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="grey">
  <row>
    <div class="col-3">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Carrers</li>
        <li>Blogs</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Carriers</li>
        <li>Blogs</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Carriers</li>
        <li>Blogs</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Carriers</li>
        <li>Blogs</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </row>
</footer>
```

Comment: You have some typos in your code. In CSS ```.row``` should be ```row``` as its a tag and ```col-5``` should be ```col-3``` and the percentage you are using for ```col``` seems random please use it according to your elements. eg ```width: 25%``` if you have 4 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want your `<ul>` to be horizontal, you have used `row` incorrectly.
It should have been applied as class and not to be used as a Tag, considering you are using bootstrap.
Read more about the bootstrap griding system from here - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.row::after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="grey">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Carrers</li>
        <li>Blogs</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Carriers</li>
        <li>Blogs</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Carriers</li>
        <li>Blogs</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Carriers</li>
        <li>Blogs</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </row>
</footer>
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.row::after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.col-5 {
 width: 41.66%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="grey">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Carrers</li>
        <li>Blogs</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Carriers</li>
        <li>Blogs</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Carriers</li>
        <li>Blogs</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Carriers</li>
        <li>Blogs</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this navigational unordered list horizontal, you have basically two options:

Make the list items inline instead of the default block. .li { display: inline; } This will not force breaks after the list items and they will line up horizontally as far as they are able.
Float the list items. Since we very often want our list items to display as blocks so we are able to set fixed widths on them, we are forced to float them to the left or right to line them up horizontally.

Source:

https://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/